# phpMyAdmin: error creating database on fresh install MAMP

Tags: phpmyadmin

Just installed MAMP on OSX 10.6.8. Apache/MSQL servers both running. Go to phpMyAdmin, create database and after hitting "Create", I get an error:
db_create.php: Missing parameter: new_db

I trashed it all, re-downloaded the install, re-installed and same thing.

I notice the "Collation" select is set on Collation and I'm not seeing the default collation set but I guessed that was due to the Mac version/this version of phpMyAdmin.

Since I'm doing this via the gui, there isn't any code entered wrong.

What could I be missing? I will ultimately install Drupal for local testing.

oh, and trying the standard
    CREATE [dbname] 
in a SQL window I get:
import.php: Missing parameter: import_typeDocumentation
import.php: Missing parameter: formatDocumentation

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled Mamp and removed previous alias. Somehow, having an alias in my dock to the previous install messed it up. Trashed that, ran MAMP by double-clicking the app, then added new icon to dock and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone I went around the block reinstalling to no avail. Checked the apache error logs and for some reason - a company machine - php-myadmin was looking for a bunch of the db_*.php files in a distant directory. I copied them across and so far so good.